# would this code avoid to leak memory?

Tags: c++

I am not sure about the code below would cause any memory leak?

```
char **a;
a = new char* [m];
a[0] = new char[m * n]; // allocate all need
for(int i=1; i<m; i++)
{
a[i] = a[i-1] + n;//allocate every pointer
}
delete[] a[0];
delete[] a;
```

Answer (score 4):

If your code runs to completion there are no memory leaks.  If any exception is thrown though then you will leak.

Comment: You leak if the line `a[0] = new char[m * n];` throws. Every other statement that's executed after memory is allocated is no-throw.

Answer (score 3):

That's fine.  You have two allocations, and two deallocations, with matching types and matching pointers.  You won't leak any memory.

Comment: Unless an allocation fails and exception will be thrown. Don't don't don't don't don't use manual allocation, unless you REALLY need it.

Comment: If you care about OOM situations where new throws, then you're right.  I'm used to embedded allocators that don't throw, they just hard-reset the box :-)

Comment: It is true, quite ugly code, i think, but i just want to sure this one dose the work

Answer (score 1):

If the second `new` fails, then it will throw an exception and the first allocation will not be deleted, giving a leak.

The best way to avoid this is to use a resource-managing class, rather than manually managing memory. In this case, `std::vector` would be best:

```
std::vector<char> memory(m * n);
std::vector<char*> pointers;

pointers.reserve(m);
pointers.push_back(&memory.front());
for (int i = 1; i < m; ++i) {
    pointers.push_back(pointers.back() + n);
}
```

Now, the destructors are guaranteed to be called whether the code completes normally or throws an exception, so there will be no leak in either case.

Comment: vector container gives us huge convenience, I agree that, but on the cost of efficiency, isn't it?

Comment: Unless optimisations are disabled, or you have a very bad implementation, then it should be just as efficient as a manually-managed array. My code should behave almost identically to yours: two memory allocations, `m` assignments, and two deallocations, and all the function calls should be inlined. There may be a cost for exception-safety, depending on how exceptions are managed, but you'd incur some cost however you tried to fix the leak.